# Android Gridview show blue background, how to change the background to white?

Tags: android, gridview, background

when i start my apps gridview show blue background i want to set white background how to set

here i put my xml and imge

> Gridview.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bodyfirst"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="15dp"
        <GridView
               android:id="@+id/gridview"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:numColumns="3" 
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:background="@android:color/white">
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: please provide your item xml

Answer (score 3):

you should add background to `LinearLayout`,this code is correct,for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="115px"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_marginTop="13.0dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

and you should add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to LinearLayout
[image]